# npm XLSX.read() Error: Invalid HTML: could not find <table>

Tags: javascript, npm, xlsx

I am trying to read excel file in ReactJS application. I have used XLSX to perform the task. Following is the code that I have used:

```
        const readFile = await fetch('../../public/images/Book1.xlsx');
        var workbook = await (readFile).arrayBuffer();
        const data = XLSX.read(workbook);
```

But on executing, I am getting error: ***Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid HTML: could not find table***

I have followed https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs/issues/1110 for help and tried moving xlsx file to public folder, but still getting same issue.

readFile.status=200 even if I enter wrong file extension. I doubt whether file is fetched properly or not

Can someone help in proceeding with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could try is to pass the workbook data to XLSX using a Blob object instead of an ArrayBuffer. Here's an example of how you could do that:

```
const response = await fetch('../../public/images/Book1.xlsx');
const data = await response.blob();
const workbook = XLSX.read(data, { type: 'blob' });
```

In this example, we first use fetch to retrieve the workbook data as a Blob object, and then pass that object to XLSX using the type: 'blob' option.

Comment: I tried with this method, but I am getting error: ***Unrecognized type blob***

Also the blob object(data) has following properties: {size: 1719,type:"text/html"}. I am not sure how type is coming as text/html when this is xlsx file.

Comment: Got the issue. Path was not correct. I changed path to fetch('./images/Book1.xlsx') after moving xlsx file to public folder. Now it is working as expected.